# Enhance/smooth raster values caused by noise

Tags: image-processing, filtering, raster, smoothing

I need to enhance or smooth a raster area (GMT grid) where noise is causing problems. The issue is that no raw data are available to do reprocessing, hence, values need to be directly modified/atenuated in the grid. Enclosed please find an image of the original grid with no histogram equalization and with equalization (red = high backscatter values, green = low backscatter values). Grid visualization thanks to the neat MIRONE software.

[image]

[image]

Any support is welcomed,

Comment: no raw data means you only have these colour maps?

Comment: actually I have the original grid and it can be converted to XYZ values, but the original values (ie. raw data) are no longer available.

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained how you hope to enhance the image ---
 using what kind of logic? For smoothing, in R, see `raster::focal`

Comment: I suspect that values in the problematic region are higher than the "common" values, this is because there is a clear artefact in the histogram equalization image where it changes from green to red (in the image it should say "this area should be green?")

Comment: There are literally millions of method to reduce noise. Depending on how the data was generated (you mention backscatter, is it SEM?), different methods might be applicable. However, removing imaging artifacts is impossible unless you can model them somehow. There's no magic "remove noise" algorithm (unfortunately).